# PHP results from multiple tables but in the same database

Tags: php, localhost

ive got my php SELECT query working but i need it to display more then 1 table worth of data.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from paymentPersonal where `custID`='$custID'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> custID: ". $row["custID"]. " - FirstName: ". $row["firstname"]. " LastName" . $row["lastname"] .  " - Mobile: ". $row["mobile"]. " - homephone: ". $row["homephone"]. " - Email: ". $row["email"]."<br>";
```

this is the code that displays the data for the 1 table but i need serveral and ive tried changing it to this to see wether it would display more tables:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from `paymentPersonal`, `paymentsPayment` where `custID`='$custID'";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<br> custID: ". $row["custID"]. " - FirstName: ". $row["firstname"]. " LastName" . $row["lastname"] .  " - Mobile: ". $row["mobile"]. " - homephone: ". $row["homephone"]. " - Email: ". $row["email"]."<br>";

             echo "<br> custID: ". $row["custID"]. " - CcName: ". $row["nameoncard"]. " CcNumber" . $row["ccnumber"] .  " - ccYear: ". $row["year"]. " - ccMonth: ". $row["month"]. " - ccCode: ". $row["code"]."<br>";
```

but without any luck just getting an error saying;

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/horizonphotography/findingcode.php on line 19
0 results
```

(FYI the `custID` is in all of the tables) if you have an idea on how to display the data on this other table please help! thank you!

Comment: You want to display data from two tables..?done

Comment: try with this `$sql =  "SELECT paymentPersonal.custID as    paymentPersonalCust,paymentsPayment.custID as   paymentsPaymentCust from paymentPersonal Left join  paymentsPayment on  paymentsPayment.custID = paymentPersonal.custID  where paymentsPayment.custID='$custID'";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Added join for get data from multiple tables**

```
$sql = "SELECT paymentPersonal.custID as paymentPersonalCust,paymentsPayment.custID as paymentsPaymentCust from paymentPersonal Left join paymentsPayment on paymentsPayment.custID = paymentPersonal.custID where paymentsPayment.custID='$custID'";
```

**Change Key of array**

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> custID: ". $row["paymentPersonalCust"]. " - FirstName: ". $row["firstname"]. " LastName" . $row["lastname"] .  " - Mobile: ". $row["mobile"]. " - homephone: ". $row["homephone"]. " - Email: ". $row["email"]."<br>";

         echo "<br> custID: ". $row["paymentsPaymentCust"]. " - CcName: ". $row["nameoncard"]. " CcNumber" . $row["ccnumber"] .  " - ccYear: ". $row["year"]. " - ccMonth: ". $row["month"]. " - ccCode: ". $row["code"]."<br>";
```

Comment: i got an error bacially saying that every row was an idetified index? eg, `Notice: Undefined index: firstname in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/horizonphotography/findingcode.php on line 23` for every row... any ideas?

Comment: yes , because u are not selecting any column exclude custID in your query u need to define all

Comment: as you can probably see im new to SELECT querys... how would i fix this?

Comment: SELECT paymentPersonal.custID means selecting column custID data from paymentPersonal table now i don't no firstname is store in which table .... comma separate u add column name after select

Comment: like this??     `$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, mobile, homephone, email paymentPersonal.custID as paymentPersonalCust,paymentsPayment.custID as paymentsPaymentCust from paymentPersonal Left join paymentsPayment on paymentsPayment.custID = paymentPersonal.custID where paymentsPayment.custID='$custID'";`

Comment: just keep on getting error notices. now its saying `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object ` ill have a fiddle and see if i can guess

Answer (score 0):

you can't fetch data from more than table without using union or join (left , right , inner , outer )  statement  , that if you want to select all filed from both table or less field , if you want to select specified fields you have try something like @manindepreet singh told you in the third

```
   SELECT paymentPersonal.custID as paymentPersonalCust,paymentsPayment.custID as paymentsPaymentCust from paymentPersonal Left join paymentsPayment on paymentsPayment.custID = paymentPersonal.custID where paymentsPayment.custID='$custID'";
```